# How to read from google cloud stoage buckets using service credentials json

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I want to read from google cloud storage using gsutil using a service credentials file. 
However I don't really understand how to pass it the permissions file. 
I have tried running 
"gcloud auth activate-service-account [ACCOUNT] --key-file=KEY_FILE"
 and then running "gsutil list". However I get the following output

```
You are attempting to perform an operation that requires a project id, with none configured. Please re-run gsutil config and make sure to follow the instructions for finding and entering your default project id.
```

After authenticating with gcloud should I be able to use gsutil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have done `"gcloud auth activate-service-account [ACCOUNT] --key-file=KEY_FILE"`, the only thing you need to do is `gcloud config set project <project id>`

Note there's no `-p` option in `gsutil`

Comment: There is no `-p` option in `gsutil` but there is a `-p` for the `gsutil ls` command. Please refer to this documentation [link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/ls#options) for more information about the `gsutil ls` command.

Comment: How do we access the service credentials json on production?

Answer (score 0):

Add `-p <project id>` at your `gsutil` command or perform a `gcloud config set project <project id>` to set the project ID globally.

You can also refer to [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) for more gsutil arguments.